# Does java graphics render only the window size or everything?

Tags: java, graphics2d, java-2d

I am making a 2d path-geometry based game in java. If I have a bunch of large shapes (Path2D's) that I am rendering every frame, is java taking the time to process the whole thing, or is it only processing the parts actually in the window?

For example say I have an rectangle that is 1000 by 1000 with the top left corner at 10, 10. My window is only 100 by 100. Is java processing the whole thing, or only the part smaller than 100, 100?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can read pixels as well with that library, you could test it.

Comment: Yes, it only renders what is in the window, or else you'd be seeing shapes outside of the window. Common sense. If this isn't the answer you were expecting, please be more specific in your post. I have a feeling it may not (which is why this is a comment), but that goes to show you how if you aren't specific enough, your point won't get through

Comment: Yes, obviously I understand that it isn't actually drawing things to the screen outside the window. What I'm asking though is: is it processing the shapes outside the window, even though it isn't drawing them?

Comment: try it with a retardedly big image and see if it bugs out like 100000 by 100000 a couple of them on a 10 by 10 screen and see , ps let me know

Comment: Yes, it will need to process those shapes that are partially visible. You could use the clip rectangle of the Graphics context to determine what area it is trying to  paint. It is unlikely that it will rasterize anything beyond its clip rectangle

Comment: @Superhq2000 Your question does not mention that. "Is it processing the shapes outside the window, even though it isn't drawing them?" should be in your post. We are not mind readers; for all we know, you could have been asking about if things will show outside of the window. You'd be amazed at what people ask

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion. I've edited it to say processing instead of rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving some information, I decided to test it myself.

I made a complex shape using Path2D and rendered with the whole shape inside the window. Then, I rendered the same thing 90% outside the window, with only a small part of the shape showing.

The one that was outside the window showed much higher performance (260 FPS) than the one entirely in the window (50 FPS).

This suggests that java only processes the part of the shape actually within the window boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering is clipped to the visible portion only.

Obviously.

Comment: The clip area is set to the visible portion, but at some moment it will still "take time" to determine whether the generic shapes are inside this clip area.

Answer (score 0):

The clip area of the Graphics2D (see [getClip()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getClip%28%29)) is set automatically to the visible portion, but at some moment "Java" will still "take time" to determine whether the generic shapes are inside this clip area.

So it might be a valid optimization technique if you don't draw the shapes that are outside the visible area. Or you could draw the static shapes to an image, and then render this image.